# GBP currency conversion of Apex Charts data labels

Tags: apexcharts

I'm learning to work with Apexcharts and need to show the labels (Y axis labels an data labels) as currency (GBP) but can't seem to find the right approach. I have looked at the locale code, but really not sure how to integrate this into my chart.

I'm trying to ensure that 1000 become 1,000 etc.

Below is the chart code

```
<script>

   var options = {
     series: [

       {
       name: "Price in £s",
         data: [1000, 2000, 2500, 3000, 4800, 6000]
     }

   ],
     chart: {

     height: 350,
     type: 'bar',
     id: 'areachart-2',

           dropShadow: {
       enabled: true,
       color: '#000',
       top: 18,
       left: 7,
       blur: 10,
       opacity: 0.2
     },
     toolbar: {
       show: false
     }
   },


   colors: ['#f6564d', '#545454'],
   dataLabels: {
     enabled: false,
     textAnchor: 'middle',
     formatter: function(val, index) {
    return val.toFixed(0);
  }
   },
   stroke: {
     curve: 'straight'
   },
   title: {
       text: '',
     align: 'left'
   },
   grid: {
     borderColor: '#f1f1f1',
     row: {
       colors: ['#fff', 'transparent'], // takes an array which will be repeated on columns
       opacity: 0.5
     },
   },
   markers: {
     size: 100
   },
   xaxis: {
     categories: ['01/05/22','01/06/22','01/07/22','01/08/22','01/09/22','01/10/22'],

     title: {
       text: 'Month'
     }

   },
   yaxis: {

       min:00,

     title: {
       text: 'Price in GBP',

     },

   },
   legend: {
     position: 'top',
     horizontalAlign: 'right',
     floating: true,
     offsetY: 100,
     offsetX: 100
   }
   };

   var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
   chart.render();


</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In `yaxis` add labels formatter

```
labels:{
  formatter: (value) => {
    return `${numberWithCommas(value)} GBP`;
  },
},
```

And use this regex to add commas

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked exactly as needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Axes labels formatting can be controlled by yaxis.labels.formatter and xaxis.labels.formatter.

```
yaxis: {
  labels: {
    formatter: function (value) {
      return value + "$";
    }
  },
},
xaxis: {
  labels: {
    formatter: function (value) {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today and fixed it by adding the labels formatter to `yaxis` as seen below:

```
yaxis: {
        labels: {
          formatter: (value) => {
            return `${parseInt(value)} GBP`;
          },
        },
        title: {
          text: "Expenses per month",
        },
      },
```

note how we perse the value and append 'GBP'

Hope that helps!